# Codechef practice question help needed - find trailing zeros in a factorial

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have been working on this for 24 hours now, trying to optimize it.  The question is how to find the number of trailing zeroes in factorial of a number in range of 10000000 and 10 million test cases in about 8 secs.

The code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int count5(int a){
    int b=0;
    for(int i=a;i>0;i=i/5){
        if(i%15625==0){
            b=b+6;
            i=i/15625;
        }
        if(i%3125==0){
            b=b+5;
            i=i/3125;
        }
        if(i%625==0){
            b=b+4;
            i=i/625;
        }
        if(i%125==0){
            b=b+3;
            i=i/125;
        }
        if(i%25==0){
            b=b+2;
            i=i/25;
        }
        if(i%5==0){
            b++;
        }
        else
            break;

    }
    return b;
}
int main(){
    int l;
    int n=0;
    cin>>l; //no of test cases taken as input
    int *T = new int[l];

    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        cin>>T[i]; //nos taken as input for the same no of test cases


    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        n=0;
        for(int j=5;j<=T[i];j=j+5){
            n+=count5(j); //no of trailing zeroes calculted 
        }
        cout<<n<<endl; //no for each trialing zero printed
    }

    delete []T;


}
```

Please help me by suggesting a new approach, or suggesting some modifications to this one.

Comment: I'd suggest adding the appropriate language/platform tag(s) to attract more of an audience.

Comment: I remember I met that problem on acm.uva.es. I didn't solve it then, so it's interesting to see the solution now.

Comment: After reading the solution: stupid problem actually. It's almost impossible to solve it during the real contest not knowing the solution.

Comment: @Roman - not really. You don't need to know that theorem, you can easily figure out the formula in this case. You know you have a trailing zero when you multiply something by 10. 10 = 2 * 5. Then, it's obvious that 2 appears a lot more times as a factor than 5 does in N!, so it's enough to count the 5s, and you get the formula (How many times does a multiple of x appear in between the numbers 1 through N? N / x of course). This is actually an easy one for a contest :).

Comment: @IVlad: "N/x of course". So in 100! how many trailing zeros? Be quick!

Comment: In 100! We have 100 / 5 = 20 multiples of 5. However, we must also account for powers of 5, because 25 and its multiples actually "contain" (at least) two fives (25 = 5*5), so we must also add the multiples of 25, which are 100 / 25 = 4. So 20 + 4 = 24 zeroes in 100!

Comment: @IVlad: yes, that's the correct answer. But it's a bit more than a simple division. You implicitly applied the theorem ;-)

Comment: @Nick D: well, yes, it still uses the theorem. I guess my point is that the theorem isn't something unreasonable that one cannot figure out on his own during a contest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following theorem:

> If p is a prime, then the highest
> power of p which divides n! (n
> factorial) is [n/p] + [n/p^2] +
> [n/p^3] + ... + [n/p^k], where k is
> the largest power of p <= n, and [x] is the integral part of x.

Reference: [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/theprimepowerdividingafactorial)

Comment: this theoram does the trick execution time = 0.56 seconds thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

The optimal solution runs in `O(log N)` time, where `N` is the number you want to find the zeroes for. Use this formula:

`Zeroes(N!) = N / 5 + N / 25 + N / 125 + ... + N / 5^k`, until a division becomes 0. You can read more on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero).

So for example, in C this would be:

```
int Zeroes(int N)
{
    int ret = 0;
    while ( N )
    {
        ret += N / 5;
        N /= 5;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This will run in 8 secs on a sufficiently fast computer. You can probably speed it up by using lookup tables, although I'm not sure how much memory you have available.

Here's another suggestion: don't store the numbers, you don't need them! Calculate the number of zeroes for each number when you read it.

If this is for an online judge, in my experience online judges exaggerate time limits on problems, so you will have to resort to ugly hacks even if you have the right algorithm. One such ugly hack is to not use functions such as `cin` and `scanf`, but instead use `fread` to read a bunch of data at once in a char array, then parse that data (DON'T use sscanf or stringstreams though) and get the numbers out of it. Ugly, but a lot faster usually.

Comment: it's the application of the theorem @Moron mentioned. In theory we have to calculate the exponents for `2` and `5` to see how many `10`s (aka trailing zeros) exist. But since `5`'s exponent is always less than `2`'s, in practice we don't need the latter.

Comment: I would try `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` first before giving up on `std::cin`.

Answer (score 1):

This question is from codechef.

http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL

How about this solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = {5, 25, 125, 625, 3125, 15625, 78125, 390625, 1953125, 9765625, 48828125, 244140625};

int main()
{
    int i, j, l, n, ret = 0, z;
    scanf("%d", &z);
    for(i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        ret = 0;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for(j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            l = n / a[j];
            if(l <= 0)
                break;
            ret += l;
        }
        printf("%d\n", ret);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any optimizations???

Answer (score 1):

Knows this is over 2 years old but here's my code for future reference:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

inline int read()
{
    char temp;
    int x=0;
    temp=getchar_unlocked();
    while(temp<48)temp=getchar_unlocked();
    x+=(temp-'0');
    temp=getchar_unlocked();
    while(temp>=48)
    {
        x=x*10;
        x+=(temp-'0');
        temp=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    int T,x,z;
    int pows[]={5,25,125,625,3125,15625,78125,390625,1953125,9765625,48828125,244140625};
    T=read();
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        x=read();
        z=0;
        for(int j=0;j<12 && pows[j]<=x;j++)
            z+=x/pows[j];
        printf("%d\n",z);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It ran in 0.13s

Answer (score 1):

Here is my accepted solution. Its score is 1.51s, 2.6M. Not the best, but maybe it can help you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void calculateTrailingZerosOfFactoriel(int testNumber)
{

    int numberOfZeros = 0;
    while (true) 
    {

        testNumber = testNumber / 5;
        if (testNumber > 0) 
            numberOfZeros += testNumber;
        else
            break;
    }
    cout << numberOfZeros << endl;
}

int main() 
{

    //cout << "Enter number of tests: " << endl;
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) 
    {
        int testNumber;
        cin >> testNumber;
        calculateTrailingZerosOfFactoriel(testNumber);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main(void) {
    long long int t, n, s, i, j;
    scanf("%lld", &t);
    while (t--) {
        i=1; s=0; j=5;
        scanf("%lld", &n);
        while (i != 0) {
            i = n / j;
            s = s + i * (2*j + (i-1) * j) / 2;
            j = j * 5; 
        }
        printf("%lld\n", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You clearly already know the correct algorithm. The bottleneck in your code is the use of cin/cout. When dealing with very large input, cin is extremely slow compared to scanf.

scanf is also slower than direct methods of reading input such as fread, but using scanf is sufficient for almost all problems on online judges.

This is detailed in the [Codechef FAQ](http://www.codechef.com/wiki/faq), which is probably worth reading first ;)

Comment: thanks for the info I tried scanf and printf but they are not effective

Comment: @user308897 A more precise link would be helpful.