# the number of trailing zeros in a factorial of a given number - Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math, factorial

Having a little trouble trying calculate the number of trailing zeros in a factorial of a given number. This is one of the challenges from Codewars- can't get mine to pass.

```
zeros(12) = 2       #=> 1 * 2 * 3 .. 12 = 479001600
```

I think I'm on the wrong path here and there is probably a more elegant ruby way. This is what I have down so far.

```
def zeros(n) 
    x = (1..n).reduce(:*).to_s.scan(/[^0]/)
    return 0 if x == [] 
    return x[-1].length if x != [] 
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa more elegant way... :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit That is a phrase, not a question.

Comment: @sawa Count of trailing zeros.. OP want..

Comment: Where did you get this problem (count trailing zeroes)? I've seen it before.

Comment: Here's a working solution :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/23762680/125816

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Your solution, as well as the OP's solution, has nothing to do with factorial. It is just counting trailing zeros of an arbitrary number.

Comment: @sawa: true. But it calculates factorial first. Doesn't it get the job done? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, your answer is appropriate for the question, but the question is inappropriate. It is not stated in the smallest form possible. If it were intended to be solved that way, then it should just ask for counting trailing zeros. No need to mention factorials.

Comment: @sawa: we both well know that not many users ask good properly-scoped questions. So one can make some assumptions.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2575373/2336725 (that one is c++, but the programming language isn't that important to the problem).

Answer (score 25):

This is more of a math question. And you're right, you are off on a wrong path. (I mean the path you are on is going to lead to a very inefficient solution)

Try to reduce the problem mathematically first. (BTW you are shooting for a log N order algorithm.)

In my answer I will try to skip a few steps, because it seems like a homework question.

The number of trailing zeros is going to be equal to the total power of 5s in the multiplication of the series.

the numbers between 1 and n will have `n/5`, `n/25`, `n/125` numbers which are multiples of 5s, 25s, 125s respectively... and so on.

Try to take these hints and come up with an algorithm to count how many powers of `10` will be crammed in to that factorial.

### Spoilers Ahead

I've decided to explain in detail below so if you want to try and solve it yourself then stop reading, try to think about it and then come back here.

Here is a step by step reduction of the problem

### 1.

The number of trailing zeros in a number is equivalent to the power of 10 in the factor of that number

e.g.

- `40 = 4 * 10^1` and it has 1 trailing zero
- `12 = 3 * 4 * 10^0` so it has 0 trailing zeros
- `1500 = 3 * 5 * 10^2` so it has 2 trailing zeros

### 2.

The number power of 10 in the factors is the same as the minimum of the power of 2 and power of 5 in the factors

e.g.

- `50 = 2^1 * 5^2` so the minimum power is 1
- `300 = 3^1 * 2^2 * 5^2` so the minimum is 2 (we are only concerned with the minimum of the powers of 2 and 5, so ignore powers of 3 and all other prime factors)

### 3.

In any factorial there will be many more powers of 2 than the powers of 5

e.g.

- `5! = 2^3 * 3^1 * 5^1`
- `10! = 2^8 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 7^1`

As you can see the power of 2 is going to start increasing much faster so the power of 5 will be the minimum of the two.

Hence all we need to do is count the power of 5 in the factorial.

### 4.

Now lets focus on the power of 5 in any `n!`

- `4! ~ 5^0`
- `5! ~ 5^1` (up to `9!`)
- `10! ~ 5^2` (up to `14!`)
- `15! ~ 5^3` (up to `19!)
- `20! ~ 5^4` (up to `24!`)
- `25! ~ 5^6` (notice the jump from `5^4` to `5^6` because the number 25 adds two powers of 5)

### 5.

The way I'd like to count the total power of five in a factorial is... count all the multiples of 5, they all add one power of 5. Then count all the multiples of 25, they all add an extra power of 5. Notice how 25 added two powers of 5, so I can put that as, one power because it's a multiple of 5 and one extra power because it's a multiple of 25. Then count all the multiple of 125 (`5^3`) in the factorial multiplication, they add another extra power of 5... and so on.

### 6.

So how'd you put that as an algorithm ?

lets say the number is `n`. So...

- `pow1 = n/5` (rounded down to an integer)
- `pow2 = n/25`
- `pow3 = n/125`

and so on...

Now the total power `pow = pow1 + pow2 + pow3 ...`

### 7.

Now can you express that as a loop?

Comment: Maybe my math is very rusty, but I have no idea where you are going with this :/

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I guess I'll explain the whole thing.

Comment: I can remember now my 8th standard math classes.. our teacher used to explain things in this way.. Good job.

Comment: @Spundun You remembered... But for me it sold out..:-) Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 6):

So, now that @Spunden has so artfully let the cat out of the bag, here's one way to implement it.

**Code**

```
def zeros(n)
  return 0 if n.zero?
  k = (Math.log(n)/Math.log(5)).to_i
  m = 5**k
  n*(m-1)/(4*m)
end
```

**Examples**

```
zeros(3)   #=>  0
zeros(5)   #=>  1
zeros(12)  #=>  2
zeros(15)  #=>  3
zeros(20)  #=>  4
zeros(25)  #=>  6
zeros(70)  #=> 16
zeros(75)  #=> 18
zeros(120) #=> 28
zeros(125) #=> 31
```

**Explanation**

Suppose `n = 128`.

Then each number between one and `128` (inclusive) that is divisible by `5^1=>5` provides at least one factor, and there are `128/5 => 25` such numbers.  Of these, the only ones that provide more than one factor are those divisible by `5^2=>25`, of which there are `128/25 => 5` (`25, 50, 75, 100, 125`). Of those, there is but `128/125 => 1` that provides more than two factors, and since `125/(5^4) => 0`, no numbers contribute more than three divisors.  Hence, the total number of five divisors is:

```
128/5 + 128/25 + 128/125 #=> 31
```

(Note that, for `125`, which has three divisors of `5`, one is counted in each of these three terms; for `25`, `50`, etc., which each have two factors of `5`, one is counted in each of the first terms.)

For arbitrary `n`, we first compute the highest power `k` for which:

```
5**k <= n
```

which is:

```
k <= Math.log(n)/Math.log(5)
```

so the largest such value is:

```
k = (Math.log(n)/Math.log(5)).to_i
```

As @spundun noted, you could also calculate `k` by simply iterating, e.g.,

```
last = 1
(0..1.0/0).find { |i| (last *= 5) > n }
```

The total number of factors of five is therefore

```
(n/5) + (n/25) +...+ (n/5**k)
```

Defining:

```
r = 1/5,
```

this sum is seen to be:

```
n * s
```

where

```
s = r + r**2 +...+ r**k
```

The value of `s` is the sum of the terms of a geometric series.  I forget the formula for that, but recall how it's derived:

```
s  = r + r**2 +...+ r**k
sr =     r**2 +...+ r**(k+1)

s-sr = r*(1-r**k)

s = r*(1-r**k)/(1-r)
```

I then did some rearrangement so that only only integer arithmetic would be used to calculate the result.

Comment: Nice reduction. You may want to take care of `n=0` case. I was convinced that your approach will be slower than simply looping, multiplying 5 every time, but ruby benchmarking leaves me not convinced. I think either way the function is just very very fast with `log(n)` order. (in your code `log(n)` order time comes from having to compute `log(n)` itself). Also, in theory there is a chance that you get wrong ratio integer because of a round-off error, but I think that probability might be infinitesimal. I want to benchmark both approaches in C but am too lazy to try it right now.

Comment: Plus I'm not sure where the fastest implementation of log function is.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @Spundun.  I initially had `return 0 if n < 5`, but thought it wasn't necessary, forgetting about the case of `n` being zero.  I don't think round-off is an issue.  The only place where it could occur is in the `log` calculations and that could be easily dealt with.  The subsequent calculation is always integer-valued.

Answer (score 2):

```
def zeros(n)
    zeros = 0
    zeros += n /= 5 while n >= 1
    zeros
end
```

Comment: Two other posts on this page use this approach.  Are you adding something new?

Comment: im not adding anything simply the shortest bit of code that I currently see among the rest of the answers

Answer (score 1):

If N is a number then number of trailing zeroes in N! is

`N/5 + N/5^2 + N/5^3 ..... N/5^(m-1) WHERE (N/5^m)<1`

You can learn [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdz_KouqHx4) how this formula comes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is easier to read:

```
def zeros(num)
  char_array = num.to_s.split('')
  count = 0

  while char_array.pop == "0"
    count += 1
  end

  count
end
```

Let me know what you think and feel free to edit if you see an improvement!

Comment: Matthew, you could also use a regex: `num.to_s[/0*$/].size`. If, for example, num = 128!, `num.to_s[/0*$/].size #=> 31`.

Comment: Actually finding the factorial is a very inefficient approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The article A Note on Factorial and its Trailing Zeros in GanitCharcha is insightful and has explained the Mathematics behind this well. Take a look.

http://www.ganitcharcha.com/view-article-A-Note-on-Factorial-and-it's-Trailing-Zeros.html

Comment: It's better to have the material here, not behind a link.  Does the link add any information that is not already here?

Answer (score 0):

```
    n=int(input())
    j=5
    c=int(0)
    while int(n/j)>0:
        c=c+int(n/j)
        j=j*5
    print(c)
```

Comment: Does this work for `30!`? [http://www.tsm-resources.com/alists/fact.html](http://www.tsm-resources.com/alists/fact.html) gives `30!` as 26525285981219105863630848**0000000** (7 trailing zeros). The code here returns 6.

Comment: I think it should be `while int(n/j) > 0`

Comment: wrote 1 instead of 0.

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
def zeros(n)
  trailing_zeros = []
  fact = (1..n).inject(:*)
  fact.to_s.split('').reverse.select {|x| break if (x.to_i != 0); trailing_zeros << x}
  return trailing_zeros.count
end
```

Comment: Actually finding the factorial is a very inefficient approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int (raw_input())
count = 0
num = 1
for i in xrange(n+1):
        if i != 0:
            num = num * i

while(num >= 10):

    if num%10 == 0:
       count+=1
       num = num/10
    else:
        break

print count
```

Comment: Is this different from existing answers? Is it as simple as it gets?

Comment: Actually finding the factorial is a very inefficient approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the explanation given  by @spundan and apart from @cary's code you can find number of trailing zero by just very simple and efficient way..see below code..

```
def zeros(n)
    ret = 0
    while n > 0 do 
        ret += n / 5
        n = n/5
    end
    ret
end
```

For example **zeros(100000000)** this will give you output -> **24999999**
With the time **Time Elapsed -> 5.0453e-05**(Just See **5.0453e-05** )
This is the part of even milliseconds.

Comment: If two other answers have the necessary code, what does your answer add to this page?

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
i  =5
n = 100
k = n

while(n/i!=0):
    count+=(n/i)
    i=i*5
    n = k
print count
```

Comment: Don't just write code only answers. Explain what your solution does!

Answer (score 0):

```
def zeros(n)
  n < 5 ? 0 : (n / 5) + zeros(n / 5)
end
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help. Also, since other answer spent a lot of effort on time complexity, did you consider duration?