# Number of trailing zeros of N

Tags: java, factorial

I am writing a method which calculates the number of trailing zeros in a factorial of a given number.

> For example:
>
> 6! = 720 --> 1trailing zero
>
> 12! = 479001600 --> 2 trailing zero

Here is my code

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class TrailingZeros
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 12;
        System.out.println(solution(n));
    }

    public static int solution(int n)
    {
        // computing factorial
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            result = result.multiply(new BigInteger(i + ""));
        }

        String str = String.valueOf(result);
        int count = 0;
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

        // counting numbers of trailing zeros
        for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (chars[i] != '0')
                break;
            count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Its working fine. But I think it is not an efficient algorithm. Please help and thank you.

Comment: this is not really the exact place for this question

Comment: perhaps this question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: There is a way to do it directly without computing the actual factorial. Saw it in a question here last week.

Comment: You may be able to play around with prime factors to make a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: refer this, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-trailing-zeroes-factorial-number/

Comment: Also [the number of trailing zeros in a factorial of a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23977772/823393) for a good description of an efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with your current approach, per se.  But we can actually count trailing zeroes using a one-liner, comparing the length of the original number string to the length of the number with trailing zeroes removed:

```
String input = "479001600";
int numZeroes = input.length() - input.replaceAll("0+$", "").length();
System.out.println(numZeroes);

2
```

### Demo

Comment: I feel that the OP's version would be quicker

Comment: @ScaryWombat Quicker, perhaps.  Easier to read and maintain, that's another story.

Comment: Yeah, agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Below will work even if number is `long`;

```
  String string = "479001600";
  int counter = 0;
  while (counter < string.length() && string.charAt(string.length() - 1 - counter) == '0') {
    counter++;
  }
  System.out.println(counter);

// Output will 2
```

Working demo 

## here

Comment: if string = 0? If string = 6

Answer (score 1):

You only need to know how many time the factor 10 is in the factorial of n. 10 is a factor of two prime: 2 and 5, so the number of times 10 is multiplied is the minimum number of appearances of 2 and 5.

How about something like:

```
public static int solution(int n)
{
    int twos = 0;
    int fives = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        twos += countFactors(i, 2);
        fives += countFactors(i, 5);
    }

    return Math.min(twos, fives);
}

static int countFactors(int n, int fac) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n >= fac && (n%fac) == 0) {
        n /= fac;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

UPDATE:

As @david-conrad noted, the twos are much more frequent than the fives, so we only need to count the fives:

```
public static int solution(int n)
{
    int fives = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        fives += countFactors(i, 5);
    }

    return fives;
}

static int countFactors(int n, int fac) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n >= fac && (n%fac) == 0) {
        n /= fac;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

UPDATE 2: Here is a demo: http://rextester.com/DWIO77242

Comment: You will quickly discover that 2s are much more common than 5s and thus 5 is the limiting factor. The limiting reagent, in chemistry terms.

Comment: @DavidConrad you must be right. In other words, we would only need to count the fives?

Comment: That is correct.